# Conditional Styling according to values in Props.Children

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am having a `div` with `props.children`. That `div` have `className = "tags"`. If there is no values passed from parent, I want to add another className `dnone` to the `div`. How to conditionally add class to that `div` if no value is passed?

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the class `dnone` to the div if there are no children? You could check for this via `props.children == null`

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it with a simple [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
  <div className={this.props.children ? 'tags' : ''}> ... </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using `classnames` package.

```
import classNames from 'classnames'
...

const cls = classNames({tags: true, dnone: !props.children })

<div className={cls}> ... </div>
```

How this works is: the class tag going to be present always and the class **dnone** is going to be present only if there is no children.

In simple words:

```
classNames({
  classA: true,
  classB: true,
  classC: false // this class is going to be excluded
})
```

Comment: No need of such overhead for this very simple task.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ It's a general-purpose solution that could be used throughout the app--seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: I think this is pretty simple and clean and much more scalable if you have more than one condition. Doing this with ternary is `<div className=\`tags ${!this.props.children ? "tags" : ""}\`>` well with just one condition is not that clean.

Comment: This is an additional package, do not answer to specific op question and not helps OP to understand how javscript works

Comment: @DaveNewton I use classnames package in my projects but the OP seems to not being able to grasp both conditionals and and javascript. Eg: Before you go with Symfony 4, I want to be sure that you know the PHP basis. Reading the question it seems a "first hand on" project.